# Delete list (inside a column) with more than one element and transform it to regular column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe which looks as this:

```
 id 
444343                           [2]
50224018                         [7]
4284                             [2]
226818                         [2, 36]
28484                       [29, 15, 52114, 47]
229261                          [20]
```

This dataframe is consequence of this line of code:

```
df= df.groupby('id').station.unique()
```

which gave me the unique stations for each group inside the dataframe.
Now I need to delete all rows that have more than one station, and to convert this row to the regular integer number. For the concrete example:

```
 ID                            station
444343                           2
50224018                         7
4284                             2
229261                          20
```

But I can't even access to this column, I tried to add it name `df.columns = ["number_from", "station"]`, to access it with index.. Nothing. -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `transform` with `nunique`

```
df1=df[df.groupby('id').station.transform('nunique')==1].copy()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! But the problem is that I do not know how to access to that column, when I typed that I got: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'station'

Comment: @Anajlim  this is from the original df not the df after df.groupby('id').station.unique()

Comment: I tested it now, but I dont get the groups that only have one station. :/

Comment: So my dataset is something like this:

https://ibb.co/TPpTh6x
And the result should be rows with the id 2 and 3, because those are groups which only contain one/same station

Answer (score 2):

you can do:

```
df=df[df.station.str.len().eq(1)].assign(station=df.station.str[0])
```

---

```
         id   station
0    444343        2
1  50224018        7
2      4284        2
5    229261       20
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! But the problem is that I do not know how to access to that column, when I typed that I got: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'station'

Comment: @Anajlim replace station with the column name which has the lists

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":[1,2,3,4,5],
                       "station":[[2],[7],[2],[2,36],[29, 15, 52114, 47]]})

df['more_than_one_station'] = df['station'].apply(lambda x:True if len(x)>1 else False)

df = df[df["more_than_one_station"]==False]

df['station'] = df['station'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x))

df.drop(['more_than_one_station'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```